TS2339: Property 'DropdownToggle' does not exist on type 'DropdownContextTypeProps | null' How can I solve the error?
import './DropdownMenu.scss'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { createContext, ReactNode, useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { Icon } from '@/Components/Ui/Icon'

type DropdownMenuProps = {
    children: ReactNode
}

type DropdownMenuButtonProps = {
    children: ReactNode
    icon: ReactNode
}

type DropdownMenuItemsProps = {
    children: ReactNode
}

type DropdownMenuItemProps = {
    children: ReactNode
    url: string
}

type DropdownContextTypeProps = {
    dropdownOpen: boolean
    DropdownToggle: () => void
}

const DropdownMenuContext = createContext<DropdownContextTypeProps | null>(null)

export const DropdownMenu = ({ children }: DropdownMenuProps) => {
    const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const DropdownToggle = () => setDropdownOpen(!dropdownOpen)
    // DropdownContextData
    const DropdownContextData = {
        dropdownOpen,
        DropdownToggle,
    }
    return (
        <DropdownMenuContext.Provider value={DropdownContextData}>
            <div className={`dropdown-menu ${dropdownOpen ? 'open' : ''}`}>
                {children}
            </div>
        </DropdownMenuContext.Provider>
    )
}

const DropdownMenuButton = ({ children, icon }: DropdownMenuButtonProps) => {
    const { DropdownToggle } = useContext(DropdownMenuContext)
    const DropdownButtonClick = () => DropdownToggle()

    return (
        <div className="dropdown-menu__button" onClick={DropdownButtonClick}>
            <span className="dropdown-menu__button-icon">{icon}</span>
            <span>{children}</span>
            <span className="dropdown-menu__button-toggle-icon">
                <Icon icon="down" />
            </span>
        </div>
    )
}

const DropdownMenuItems = ({ children }: DropdownMenuItemsProps) => {
    return (
        <div className="dropdown-menu__items">
            <div className="dropdown-menu__items-content">{children}</div>
        </div>
    )
}

const DropdownMenuItem = ({ children, url }: DropdownMenuItemProps) => {
    return (
        <NavLink to={url} className="dropdown-menu__item">
            <span className="dropdown-menu__item-icon">
                <Icon icon="circle" />
            </span>
            <span>{children}</span>
        </NavLink>
    )
}

DropdownMenu.Button = DropdownMenuButton
DropdownMenu.Items = DropdownMenuItems
DropdownMenu.Item = DropdownMenuItem

The code works fine. There is a problem with the line below but I could not solve it. I sent the DropdownToggle element to the context as value but it cannot find it.

TS2339: Property 'DropdownToggle' does not exist on type 'DropdownContextTypeProps | null'.

const { DropdownToggle } = useContext(DropdownMenuContext)

I sent the DropdownToggle element to the context as value but it cannot find it.

You've initialized your context to null, and null cannot be destructured. You'll first need to check the type:
const dropdownMenuContext = useContext(DropdownMenuContext);

if (dropdownMenuContext === null) {
  // Handle the `null`, for example, by early returning:
  return null;
}

// Now you can pull the toggle out of the context
const { DropdownToggle } = dropdownMenuContext;

Minor nit: please don't name functions starting with a capital letter, it makes them look like components.

Thank you very much for the minor nit, it is very valuable :)
